# MySQL shows incorrect autoincrement value after bulk insertion

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, auto-increment

I have run a MySQL query to insert records to a table (A) from table B in another DB using INSERT .....SELECT.

There are 18997 records inserted successfully. But then what I am seeing is the next new record takes value 32768  where as the expected one is 18997+1 = 18998.

I repeated the insertion many times after truncating the content. Everytime the autoinc value is 1 before the bulk insertion but after the insertion , teh last record has id 18997 and table shows next counter 32768.

Table is InnoDB, MySQL is 5.5

Anybody has an idea why this is happening?

Comment: execute and post results for `show create table table_name;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the explanation here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-modes